# how to not include the value that breaks my loop in my list

Tags: python

```
user_input = ''
user_values = []

while True:
    if user_input in ['q' ,'Q']:
        break

    else:
        user_input = input('input:')
        user_values.append(user_input)
print(user_values)
```

The problem with this code is that it I wanted it to add all values entered in a loop in my list , and break when user enters q or Q but it somehow adds q to the list how do I prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 2):

```
if user_input == 'q' and 'Q':
```

This does *not* do what you think it does<sup>(a)</sup>, try this instead:

```
if user_input in ['q', 'Q']:
```

---

A better way would be to restructure your loop as follows:

```py
while True:
    user_input = input('input:')
    if user_input in ['q' ,'Q']:
        break
    user_values.append(user_input)
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is because of the way `and` is evaluated, if the first sub-expression is truthy, the result of the whole is the second sub-expression. This works for real boolean values but has the side effect of giving you the value of the second sub-experession, *not* a guaranteed true/false value.

Try, for example, the following in an interactive Python session:

```py
>>> 1 == 1 and 'Q'
'Q'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, follow @paxdiablo's answer, and replace `if user_input == 'q' and 'Q':` with `if user_input in ['q', 'Q']:`.

Then, move the `user_input` before the `if` statement, and print `user_values` inside the `else` clause:

```
user_input = ''
user_values = []
x = 0
while x == 0:
    user_input = input('input:')
    if user_input in ['q', 'Q']:
        break

    else:
        user_values.append(user_input)
        print(user_values)
```